# Why do I see different results in PageSpeed Insights?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I've run a PageSpeed Insights report, however the top box [top box results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBhdV.png) is showing very different results compared to the 'Diagnose performance issues' box further down the page [image in performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1HYf.png)

Why are they totally different? e.g. LCP on the top on is 7.2s and on the second image is 47.1s

I've tried running a few tests every couple of hours but they are all still like this.

Comment: I'm curious as to how you can get a message saying real world data is not available, but then it shows real world data. I've not seen that before and I help support PSI! Is that an unaltered screenshot? Can you share the URL? If the data is indeed not available but for some reason it's showing other data (from a previous run?) then that could explain the discrepancies.

Comment: @BarryPollard Definitely not edited, I just took the screenshot in two parts to remove the screenshot of the website and identifying info. I've just run the test again now though and it's no longer giving the warning about real world data not available. However, the results are still very different e.g. LCP on top is still 7.2s but below is 22.3s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data at the top is based on real-world usage through Chrome users who have opted in to sharing this performance data.

The bit below, is where PSI runs an automated Lighthouse report, on particular (often quite slow) settings and does a fresh load of the page as if they have never visited your site before (i.e. have no cached assets).

Usually these are not as far apart as you're seeing, but it's not unusual to see differences.

If the field is faster (as in your case), then the reasons could be:

- Your users are all on better hardware and networks than the settings used by PSI. PSI is a global tool so has to pick settings that roughly represent global usage. If you're serving mostly 1st world users using really fast devices, on 5G or better networks, the Lighthouse settings may not be representative for your users.
- Your users often have data cached. For example if they visit many pages in each visit, then they will be faster than a "cold load" like PSI performs. In effect PSI is the "worst case scenario" (for the given network and CPU simulation).
- Similarly things like [the bfcache](https://web.dev/bfcache/) if they click back and forth a lot can have noticeable impact on performance.
- PSI runs from [one of three locations (North America, Europe, or Asia)](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about) and maybe you're in a location that's not near those (e.g. Africa) and so this lab test is slower than for real users?
- You are seeing origin level data at the top, and URL-level data at the bottom. Therefore you are not comparing like for like.

There may also be other reasons, specific to your site, but without a URL it's difficult to guess what that might be.

The fact that you have seen these differences is one of the best things about PSI - you get to see the actual data (which just shows the Core Web Vitals) and the lab-based Lighthouse test (which gives you MUCH more detailed diagnostics). You can (and should!) use the real-world data to calibrate your lab-based data and decide what to concentrate on.

Of course it would be nice if they were closer (and usually they are!) but some URLs will be different for the reasons given above (or other reasons).